# Error using CoreML model to classify an image

Tags: python, predict, coremltools

I'm trying to use CoreML tools to convert a Keras model to coreml and I'm having an error in prediction.
First I converted the model:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(  
    model,  
    input_names='stampImage',    # Inform CoreML the input name  
    image_input_names = 'stampImage', # Inform CoreML the input for images  
    output_names='prediction',  
    class_labels = class_labels, # From labels_dict  
    predicted_feature_name='predicted_feature_name',  
    is_bgr=True) 
coreml_model.save('./trained_models_data/stamps' + version + '.mlmodel')
```

The conversion runs fine. Then I loaded the Model:

```
model =  coremltools.models.MLModel('./trained_models_data/stamps' + version + '.mlmodel')
```

And an Image:

```
from PIL import Image  
image = Image.open('C1243_LND_899FA3F6-B703-4724-9701-F11DAD7CEDFE.jpg')
```

But when I tried to predict:

```
model.predict({'stampImage': image})
```

I received an error:

```
Error: value type not convertible:  
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=714x714 at 0x1127425A8>  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-21-82fd85392a7f> in <module>()  
----> 1 model.predict({'stampImage': image})  


/anaconda/envs/coremltools_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.pyc in predict(self, data, **kwargs)  
    236         """  
    237         if self.__proxy__:  
--> 238             return self.__proxy__.predict(data)  
    239         else:  
    240             if _sys.platform != 'darwin' or float('.'.join(_platform.mac_ver()[0].split('.')[:2])) < 10.13:  


RuntimeError: value type not convertible
```

I tried to follow the steps from "Core ML in depth" session in WWDC... Somebody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should load your converted model with `CoreML` on the iOS side. For `python` use the model before conversion.